# PHP array (yaml) - add or remove sections of config file

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some software that uses a yaml config file and I want to dynamically add a list of registered users to the config file when they join and remove them when their accounts are deleted.

The config file is as follows:

```
    targets:
  users:
    - name: AlFredo01
      uid: a1fa36h2a5hbd6535c919402ba8cc837bd75abfae
      userinfo:
        - email: Alfredo01@gmail.com
        - gender: male
        - country: it
    - name: AlFredo02
      uid: jmed8d83m4mtjf7f7f8j299d8210sla9010labvab10
      userinfo:
        - email: Alfredo02@gmail.com
        - gender: male
        - country: gb
```

I effectively would like to be able to add in new names and remove by name or UID using a PHP script on register/archive.

All the info needed would be available on registration. On deleting, their UID/Name is stored in the DB exactly how it will be added to the config file.

Can this be achieved, please?

I've never used yaml files before. I've found php-yaml and I can parse the data in to an array and print or dump it.

```
 <?
$parsed = yaml_parse_file('config2.yml');
var_dump($parsed);
?>
```

The above does dump the data as you would expect. Like below

```
    Array
(
    [targets] => 
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => AlFredo01
                    [uid] => a1fa36h2a5hbd6535c919402ba8cc837bd75abfae
                    [userinfo] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [email] => Alfredo01@gmail.com
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [gender] => male
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [country] => it
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => AlFredo02
                    [uid] => jmed8d83m4mtjf7f7f8j299d8210sla9010labvab10
                    [userinfo] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [email] => Alfredo02@gmail.com
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [gender] => male
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [country] => gb
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'd like to be able to effectively remove a full block based on UID.

So if I wanted to remove Alfredo02, I'd remove this section

```
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => AlFredo02
                    [uid] => jmed8d83m4mtjf7f7f8j299d8210sla9010labvab10
                    [userinfo] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [email] => Alfredo02@gmail.com
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [gender] => male
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [country] => gb
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Based on UID: `jmed8d83m4mtjf7f7f8j299d8210sla9010labvab10`

Additionally, I'd like to be able to add a full section in for a new user.

I've tried basic lines to get things like the array ID to start with but keep getting nothing returned.

```
$search = array_search('jmed8d83m4mtjf7f7f8j299d8210sla9010labvab10', array_column($parsed, 'uid'));
```

Could anyone please help me with a method of removing and adding data? Once I can generate a new "output" with data added or removed, I can write that back to the config.yml file.

Comment: If you need help getting php-yaml installed, tell us about the problem you run into there. Don't just ask us to write code for you when you're stuck on a prerequisite that renders you unable to try and make it work yourself.

Comment: I've got yaml installed now, that wasn't the real issue.

Comment: @flyx I've updated the post above as php-yaml is now working and I can dump from the yaml_parse_file

Comment: If you think about it, this shouldn't be a yaml question. Yaml is not *native* to php, meaning you'll always transform yaml (being a string) to an array or object and vice versa. All the manipulation you're asking about will be done on that (array/object) native data structure. When you're done it will be serialized to yaml again. So the question is, where do you have problems? Manipulating the data structure or reading/writing it as yaml?

Comment: Hi @Yoshi - I want to manipulate the data in PHP and write it back to the config file. Remove data, add data and write to the config.

Comment: I am at a point where I can obviously export data, how can I remove a full block please and add a full block? I can export the data using $parsed = yaml_parse_file("config.yml"); and $array = print_r($parsed['targets']['users']); just shows the users. How can I only show a user with the name "Alfredi02" and remove his entire entry in the config, please? Thanks for your help anyone. This isn't something I've had to do before so learning.

Comment: Thanks chaps, your comments did help me focus my direction. You are right @yoshi - this is less a Yaml question and more a PHP Array question. I need to manipulate the array now I have that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through investigation and determination I have figured out a way which allows you to remove from the array and write back to the yml file with the removed block/user.

```
$search = print_r(array_search('jmed8d83m4mtjf7f7f8j299d8210sla9010labvab10', array_column($parsed[users], 'uid', true)));
unset($parsed[users][$search]);

echo '<pre>' , print_r($parsed) , '</pre>';

yaml_emit_file("config2.yml",$parsed);
```

This effectively allows you to search for your `uid` inside of `users` and then print the result on the page using `echo`, but you can remove this.

Then writing the whole output back to the yml file using `yaml_emit_file`.

The next stage will be working out how to add a new user in to the array and write that back where necessary.

I'll update when I get to that point for the benefit of others.